# How does firewalld "ingress" and "egress" work compared to the 'classic' way of masquerading IPs?

Tags: networking, router, firewall, firewalld

I'm currently on the second iteration of a home router I built myself.

On the 'original' build, I essentially wrapped the 'standard' commands in firewalld rich rules

On V1

```
 firewall-cmd --direct --add-rule ipv4 nat POSTROUTING 0 -o  enp1s0 -j MASQUERADE  
 firewall-cmd --direct --add-rule ipv4 filter FORWARD 0 -i br0 -o  enp1s0 -j ACCEPT  
 firewall-cmd --direct --add-rule ipv4 filter FORWARD 0 -i enp1s0 -o br0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT  
 firewall-cmd --runtime-to-permanent
```

I understand how this works, I've turned on masquerading, I'm telling the firewall to forward ports from the 'internal' bridged interface to the external one, and to accept already established connections from the outside.

The 'modern' version lets me add one or more interfaces to a zone, then set port forwarding for the *zones*

```
firewall-cmd --new-policy internal-external --permanent
firewall-cmd --policy internal-external --add-ingress-zone=internal --permanent
firewall-cmd --policy internal-external --add-egress-zone=external --permanent
firewall-cmd --policy internal-external --set-target=ACCEPT --permanent
```

It is a lot more elegant, easier to manage but - what does this actually do?

```
geek@router-t1:~$ sudo firewall-cmd --info-policy internal-external
[sudo] password for geek:
internal-external (active)
  priority: -1
  target: ACCEPT
  ingress-zones: internal
  egress-zones: external
  services:
  ports:
  protocols:
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:
```

I see no masquerading going on - and I was under the impression that was necessary for NAT to work - how does this work 'behind the hood' - and what mechanism is this using?

Comment: Are you sure "ingress/egress" implies NAT is being used at all? If it actually says "masquerade: no", would assume it's just the 'forward' rules (for inter-LAN routing)...

Comment: It doesn't. I'm not quite getting 'how' this works. I built the old router partially between an ars technica guide, and the mental model of a consumer router and this... works differently from what I'm, used to and I'm trying to understand what's the mechanisms in use here

Comment: Masquerading/NAT is an additional function _on top of_ the regular routing/forwarding mechanism; it's not what causes or permits the packets to be forwarded in itself, and I think firewalld tries to go a bit beyond "consumer router" functionality (with its somewhat enterprise roots) so it makes sense that it would offer them as two separate features. Have you tried comparing the resulting generated iptables (or nftables) rules between the two methods?

Comment: I did. iptables -l is blank for the new one. I forgot to take a copy of the old one, since I'm in the midst of rebuilding my router/firewall box, unfortunately, but I recall there was *something* there. They also are 'front ends' for different firewalls - the old build, that's been running for years ran legacy iptables and the new ones's running nftables

Comment: The commands to use for comparison (including with diff) are: `iptables-save` or `nft -s list ruleset`, `iptables -L` isn't very useful (especially without `-v` it generates incomplete information, and anyway it won't include all tables: won't include NAT unless specified).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've probably found an answer one way or another so this is for posterity: the external zone comes with masquerading on by default.  List the zone rather than the policy and you'll see it.

```
user@router:~$ sudo firewall-cmd --info-zone external

external (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: wan
  sources:
  services: ssh
  ports:
  protocols: icmp 
  forward: yes
  masquerade: yes
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: huh, so it does. I've taken the liberty of including the command to get that information, and the output to fill out your answer a little.